# Перевод десятичных чилел в двоичные, и обратно, в lua

Tags: lua

Как можно перевести десятичное число в двоичное, и обратно, в lua?
Есть ли нативные функции для таких операций?

Comment: [нативных, видимо, нет](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9079853/4827341).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
local bnum = '1000001010101'
print(tonumber(bnum, 2))    -- 4181

function tobin(num)
    local tmp = {}
    repeat
        tmp[#tmp+1]=num%2
        num = math.floor(num/2)
    until num==0
    return table.concat(tmp):reverse()
end

local bnum2 = tobin(4181)
print(bnum==bnum2, bnum2)   -- true    1000001010101
```